# Jetpack Compose - TextField loses focus after typing

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I have an `AlertDialog` with dynamic height. It has a `TextField`, on which some basic validation is performed, such as making sure the content is not empty. A warning message is displayed below it if validation fails. Once the user enters text in the text field, the warning message automatically disappears.

The problem is, when the user starts typing after the warning message is already displayed, the `TextField` loses focus for some reason. Does anyone know why, and how to prevent this from happening? Relevant code is below the gif. Currently using `compose:1.2.0-alpha04`

[image]

##### AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog(
    properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false),
    modifier = Modifier.width(250.dp),
    onDismissRequest = { showAddMatchDialog = false },
    buttons = {
        var player1Name by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
        var player1NameError by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
        var player1Score by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
        var player1ScoreError by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(R.string.add_match_dialog_title),
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
            )

            Spacer(Modifier.height(4.dp))

            PlayerRow(
                nameLabel = stringResource(R.string.player1_name),
                name = player1Name,
                isNameError = player1NameError,
                onNameClear = { player1Name = "" },
                onNameChange = {
                    player1Name = it
                    player1NameError = false
                },
                score = player1Score,
                isScoreError = player1ScoreError,
                onScoreChange = {
                    player1Score = it
                    player1ScoreError = false
                }
            )

            Spacer(Modifier.height(8.dp))

            // Same thing for player 2
        }
    }
)
```

##### Player Row

```
@Composable
fun PlayerRow(
    nameLabel: String,
    name: String,
    isNameError: Boolean,
    onNameClear: () -> Unit,
    onNameChange: (String) -> Unit,
    score: String,
    isScoreError: Boolean,
    onScoreChange: (String) -> Unit
) {
    Column {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            // Name TextField
            Column {
                Text(
                    text = nameLabel,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2
                )

                Spacer(Modifier.height(4.dp))

                Box {
                    BasicTextField(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(TEXT_FIELD_WIDTH.dp)
                            .height(TEXT_FIELD_HEIGHT.dp)
                            .background(
                                color = GrayLight,
                                shape = roundedCornerShape
                            )
                            .then(
                                if (isNameError) {
                                    Modifier.border(
                                        width = 1.dp,
                                        color = Warning,
                                        shape = roundedCornerShape
                                    )
                                } else {
                                    Modifier
                                }
                            )
                            .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 6.dp),
                        value = name,
                        onValueChange = onNameChange,

                        singleLine = true,
                    )

                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(start = (TEXT_FIELD_WIDTH - 25).dp, top = 3.dp)
                            .ripplelessClickable { onNameClear() },
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Clear,
                        contentDescription = "",
                        tint = Gray
                    )
                }
            }

            // Score TextField
            Column {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.score),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2
                )
                Spacer(Modifier.height(4.dp))
                BasicTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(TEXT_FIELD_HEIGHT.dp)
                        .background(
                            color = GrayLight,
                            shape = roundedCornerShape
                        )
                        .then(
                            if (isScoreError) {
                                Modifier.border(
                                    width = 1.dp,
                                    color = Warning,
                                    shape = roundedCornerShape
                                )
                            } else {
                                Modifier
                            }
                        )
                        .padding(start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp, top = 6.dp),
                    value = score,
                    onValueChange = onScoreChange,
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
                    ),
                    singleLine = true,
                )
            }
        }

        if (isNameError) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 20.dp),
                text = stringResource(R.string.enter_player_name),
                color = Warning,
                fontSize = 14.sp
            )
        }

        if (isScoreError) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 20.dp),
                text = stringResource(R.string.enter_player_score),
                color = Warning,
                fontSize = 14.sp
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. The problem is this:

```
else {
   Modifier
}
```

You cannot assign "Modifier" by itself when using .then()